# Spec Explorer - Abstract specification of behaviour

Tags: c#, testing, specifications, mbt

I am currently evaluating Spec Explorer, but I am stuck with a problem concerning abstract specifications of function behaviour.
I have something like :

```
[TypeBinding("Implementation.ImplementationElement")]
public class ModelElement
{ /*... */ }
public class ModelBehaviour
{
  [Rule]
  public static void doSomething()
  {
    ModelElement sel = SelectElement(elements);
    // ... do something with sel
  }
  private static Set<ModelElement> elements = new Set<ModelElement>();
}
```

Now I do not want to define `SelectElement(Set<ModelElement> e)` explicitly in the model program. I would prefer to specify it with a postcondition like `elements.contains(\result);`. Is this somehow possible ?

The problem with the explicit definition is that I would enforce a selection strategy.

I tried to avoid the problem in the following way (maybe I am just missing something small and someone could give me a hint to do it correctly):

1. Add a parameter `ModelElement e` to `doSomething`
2. Add condition `Condition.IsTrue(elements.Contains(e))` to `doSomething`
3. Define an action in the config-script `SelectElement`
4. Define a machine `SelectAndDo` in the config-Script as follows:

   ```
   machine SelectAndDo() : Main
   {
     let ImplementationElement e 
         Where {.Condition.IsTrue(e.Equals(SelectElement()));.} 
         in doSomething(e)
   }
   ```
5. Use `SelectAndDo` instead of `doSomething`

However, this does not work, because the exploration of the corresponding model enters an error state.
If this does not work at all, is there a good alternative to Spec Explorer on Windows, preferably stable? Can FsCheck be recommended for testing stateful systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. 
The solution sketched above worked actually, but I returned `null` from `SelectElement()` if elements was empty, so the condition in the where-clause could not be fulfilled. So instead of returning null, I decided to return an "illegal" element, similar to a Null Object.
So my whole solutions looks something like this:

The machine:

```
machine Full() : Main
{
  Init(); CreateElement();CreateOtherElement();CreateIllegal(); SelectAndDo* || ModelProgram
}
```

The `CreateIllegal()` is afaik needed, such that the Condition in `SelectAndDo` can be fulfilled.

Beside that, I added checks for this illegal value in the model program.

**EDIT:**

There is actually a nicer, straight-forward way using `Choice.Some<T>`, which I did not know.